Diffeomorphism between planar graphs with condition on volume form
Suppose to have a planar graph $T$ with the origin as unique vertex $v$, and suppose to have some volume form $\omega = a(x,y) dx \wedge dy$. Moreover, suppose that $a(x,y) = 1$ on some of the edges exiting $v$.
Is there a diffeomorphism $h \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, that "retracts" the other edges, such that $a(x,y) = 1$ on all the edges?
I'm fine if there exist only "locally". My idea was to use some Moser's Trick-idea. I imagined that since the edges are 1-dimensional, and the plane is 2-dimensional, I have enough "free space" to work with.
Edit: I just realized there is some information I need to add. $\omega = g^\ast(dx \wedge dy)$, with $g$ a diffeomorphism of the plane

To understand, your graph is embedded in the plane equipped with the area form $\omega$? When you say "retract", do you mean (i) that you shrink the edges to points, or (ii) that you want to isotop them within the plane? There is no homeomorphism that can accomplish (i). And for (ii): do you mean that you want to 'move' $T$ to $T'$ (i.e. find a new embedding $T'$ of $T$ in the plane) such that the restriction of $a$ to $T'$ equals $1$? If so, then you can produce a counter-example function $a$ whose level-set $[a=1]$ does not admit a copy of the given $T$.

Yes, $\omega$ is an area form on the plane.
My question is: can I find a diffeomorphism $g$ of the plane, such that $g^\ast(a(x,y),dx \wedge dy) = dx \wedge dy$. I ask $g$ to be the identity on the edges on which $a \equiv 1$; the other edges are allowed to be shrinked (retract was not the right word). Other information: $T$ is a tree, there are no loops exiting and entering $v$.

I imagine that 'shrinked' does not include 'shrinked to a point'. Do you allow for 'dilations' of edges? Also, your original question asks for 'a diffeo $h$ such that $a(x,y) = 1$ on all the edges, which is not the same thing as what you wrote in your comment (a $g$ such that $g^*(a(x,y) dx \wedge dy) = dx \wedge dy$ that is the identity on the edges on which $a = 1$). Perhaps you should edit your question so as to carefully describe what you aim for, with all the information that you need to add.
